# JS querySelectorAll function does not select intended css class

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, queryselector, tagname

I try to select the `careerPoints` class with JavaScript, but when I type querySelectorAll I get "undefined". Besides, when I type querySelector I can get only the first element on the loop.

This is my code:

```
<body>
  <h1>Hi</h1>

  {%for x in range(0, 16)%}
    <ul>
      <li scope="row"><p>Name:</p> {{dataName[x]['firstName']}} {{dataName[x]['lastName']}}</li>
      <li class="points"><p>Career Points</p><p class="careerPoints">{{dataName[x]['careerPoints']}}</p> </li>
      <li class="numbers"><img width="100px" src="{{dataName[x]['headShotUrl']}}" alt="{{dataName[x]['firstName']}} {{dataName[x]['lastName']}}"></li>
      <li class="numbers"><p>Height</p> {{dataName[x]['height']}}</li>
    </ul>
  {%endfor%}

  <script>
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll("careerPoints").text;
    console.log(elements);
   </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: use `(".careerPoints")` instead of `("careerPoints")`

Comment: unfortunately, I added to the point and I get undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `querySelectorAll(".careerPoints")`.

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) uses CSS selectors. In this case `.` selects the class. `#` would select the id, for example.

The other issue is this (I've added the `.` for convenience).

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".careerPoints").text;
```

`querySelectorAll` returns a nodelist, so you can't just select text from it because there is no text property on a nodelist (note: there is no `text` property at all). You need to iterate over the nodelist and then select the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) (or [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) which behaves a little differently) from each element. Here's a small example using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to log the text to the console.

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".careerPoints");
elements.forEach(element => console.log(element.textContent));
```